# MVC-3 User-Image Management - Best Practices

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-3

Developing using MVC-3, Razor, C#

Been searching around and cannot find advice I'm looking for.  My site will contain user-uploaded images (possibly a high number).  What is the best practice for managing these pictures (placement, breakdown into sub-folders, etc...)?  Where do I place them that will prevent them from getting accidentally blown away if I republish my site periodically?

If there are any good articles or blog posts, that would be helpful.  Also, any advice/tips anyone wants to add would be great.

Thanks for your time!

Rob

**EDIT**

Also would like to know what people do to prevent hot linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A site that I run and has a high volume of images, has all of the images stored in a date folder structure. i.e. 2010/Dec/31/image.jpg

There are two reasons for this.

The first is the limited amount of DB space (200 MB) came with my hosting plan. Obviously if I had gigabytes of space I would have stored them in the DB.

The second reason is to keep the number of images in the folders to a minimum. Directory listings take longer with the more files that are contained in them so a new directory every 24 hours was my workaround.

Can you perhaps tell us more about what resources you have or how many images you estimate will be uploaded daily?

Comment: Hi Sir Psycho, thanks for your response.  I may end up going with the subdirectory routine.  As this is a start-up site, I may only have a couple hundred a day but could grow to be thousands (we can only hope!).  Reviewing my web hosting plan, I don't see a restriction on db size, and I know I have unlimited bandwidth and storage space.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or above you may use FileStreams.  If the files are under 1MB in size you might even have better performance if you store them as `VARBINARY(MAX)`. The best part about storing in the database is you may easily use transactions.

As for replication and backup you may use standard database replication and backup with the files.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the space in your DB, then I recommend that, as backup/restore becomes much easier.  If you have limited space for your DB, then a folder structure would work, though I would not store more than 1000 files in a single folder.  So you'll want to come up with a solution that helps keep a folder from not holding more than 1000 images and folders in one place.  If you think you'll have less than 1000 images per day, then a variation on what Sir Psycho suggested would probably work well which would be a folder for each year, then a sub folder under the year with month and day to store all the images for that day.

To answer your question about hot linking: your best bet is to check the referrer website (which should be found in the head of the request for the image) and make sure it's coming from your domain.  If it's not, you can either not send back any information, or you send back an image that let's the user know they cannot see the image from the 3rd party site.

The header data can be spoofed, but odds are random visitors coming to the 3rd party site will not only not have done this, but probably wouldn't know/care how to.

Comment: I think the safest bet it check the origin of requests using an IP address to prevent hot linking. If you want to be fancy, you could add a water mark server side before the image is sent. Advertise your site in the process.

Comment: @Psycho - What would you compare that IP address to?  Keep a list of recent IP addresses that have requested pages?